# Delete row of data based on condition

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a spreadsheet that I want to use to store project timelines. I have the ability to add projects and their start dates and also their length until completion - this is on the "Projects" sheet. This is reflected on a separate sheet by having cells colored a specific color for each project, depending on what date they are set - this is the "Timeline" sheet. I am having a problem when I want to delete a project. I want to click on the project name's cell and click "Delete Project", from the menu I created, and then have the project row deleted on both the "Projects" sheet and the "Timeline" sheet. The loop is perplexing me and I am not fully understanding it. Should I use an array to store the project names on both sheets and then use that to reference each other, or...??? Here is what I have so far.

```
function clearProject() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getActiveRange();
  var height = sourceRange.getValues().length;
  var rowPosition = sourceRange.getRowIndex();

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Timeline');
  var targetSheetValues = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 49);
  var targetProjectNames = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).getValues();
  var sourceProjectNames = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, 15, 1).getValues();

  var targetHeight = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).length;
  var targetRowPosition = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).getRowIndex();

  for(var i=0; i > sourceProjectNames.length; i++){
    if(i == targetProjectNames){
      targetSheet.deleteRows(targetRowPosition, targetHeight);
        }
    else{
      break;
    }
  }


  //This deletes the row of the active cell
  //ss.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(rowPosition, height);

  Logger.log(i);

}
```

Also, if you know any resources that explain loops in plain English, please shoot me a link. Thank you for your help!

EDIT: Changed the comparison from = to == in the "if" statement.
EDIT 2: Changed the comparison in the `for` loop. Also, changed what the `if` statement compared.

The loop is still not working properly. When I check the logs for `i` I get `0.0` . Here is the new code...

```
 function clearProject() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Projects');
  var sourceRange = sourceSheet.getActiveRange();
  var height = sourceRange.getValues().length;
  var rowPosition = sourceRange.getRowIndex();

  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Timeline');
  var targetSheetValues = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 49);
  var sourceRangeValues = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, 15, 1);
  var targetProjectNames = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).getValues();
  var sourceProjectNames = sourceSheet.getRange(2, 1, 15, 1).getValues();

  var targetHeight = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).length;
  var targetRowPosition = targetSheet.getRange(3, 1, 15, 1).getRowIndex();

  for(var i=0; i < sourceRangeValues.length; i++){
    if( targetProjectNames[i][0] == sourceRange[i][0]){
      targetSheet.deleteRows(targetRowPosition, targetHeight);
    Logger.log(i);    
    }
  }


  //This deletes the row of the active cell
  //ss.getActiveSheet().deleteRows(rowPosition, height);

  Logger.log(i);

}
```

Comment: The biggest problem in your code is not the loop but the comparison...have a look at some doc on conditions in JavaScript,for example here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp. and here. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp

Comment: I can't believe I did not catch that! I changed the comparison, but I the code is still not working properly.

Comment: The break statement prevents the loop to work since it is always active, move it in the condition:  if(...==...){break}

Comment: @Sergeinsas I apologize, but I had removed the `break` and forgot to update the post. With the break removed, it is still doing the same thing.

Comment: You forgot the "getValues()" at the end of sourceRangeValues definition.

Comment: As it is now sourceRangeValues is a range object,not an array of values and you can't iterate it. Use the logger to see the data throughout your script

Comment: I agree with Serge. Why did you replace sourceProjectNames with sourceRangeValues

Comment: Because I do not fully understand how to accomplish what I want to do, I left logic behind and started trying different things. Of course, this would lead me to still not understanding the solution, even if I would have stumbled across the answer. I swapped it back to `i < sourceProjectNames` which makes sense about it being an array. Now my `if` statement is producing an error `Cannot read property "0" from undefined.`

Answer (score 1):

1. I don't think this loop will run even once at all

`for(var i=0; i > sourceProjectNames.length; i++)`

it should have been

```
for(var i=0; i < sourceProjectNames.length; i++)
```

2.You are comparing an integer to a 2-D array which is incorrect

`if(i == targetProjectNames)`

Instead, you should be doing something like this.

`if( targetProjectNames[i][0] == sourceProjectNames[i][0])`

3.Your `break;` statement will end the loop if the first comparison fails. So remove the else portion altogether

These are few things I could notice upfront. Give this a try and edit your question with more information if you still see problems.

Comment: What I meant was remove the else portion altogether along with the `break` - it is not needed at all. Once you've removed that, please update the question with the output you see

Comment: Sorry about that. I removed the `break` and it is still doing that same thing.